# Should cublas be outperformed by atlas?

Tags: c, cuda, cublas

According to my measurements of dgemm from both cublas and atlas, atlas severly beats cublas in terms of speed. Is this to be expected for a system with an Intel i7 950 and Nvidia GTX470?

I tested matrices of size 10x10 up to 6000x6000 in increments of 50. Atlas always wins. I measure both total application execution and just the multiplication step.

Anyone else have experience with this? Is this the expected results?

Thanks in advance.

edit: (same code, same results on a Xeon X5670  and Nvidia Tesla C2050)

edit2: It appears a great deal of slowness if attributed to initialisation of the cublas library. I continue to work on it.  I'll update here when I learn more.

Comment: No that isn't the expect result, especially for the C2050. Can you show some code and actual GFLOP/s numbers for the CUBLAS case?

Comment: Accelerators are not useful for single-shot operations since copying data to/from accelerator memory and synchronising on kernel execution could take much more time than the actual computation. You should really be doing lots of computation on data that is on the graphics card without moving it to and fro. GTX470 has it double precision performance crippled to 1/4 of what the core is capable of so it would not compete with high end Quadros and Teslas.

Comment: If you are on Linux, I recommend running nvidia-smi in persistence mode (or run it in looping mode (-l) in the background).  This can reduce device context creation from a couple of seconds to handful of milliseconds.  If you post the code you use to run and time cublas, we can help you make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the single-threaded versions of both libraries? As far as I understand, both GotoBLAS and Atlas tend to sneakily use multiple threads when working on large matrices.

That said, at large matrix sizes the algorithm used tends to matter much more than the low-level implementation. Naive matrix multiplication is O(N^3), whereas Strassen algorithm scales much better, about O(N^2.81) or so. However, Strassen algorithm happens to vectorize very nicely (to much larger SSE and AVX registers, yielding almost 2 to 8-fold increase in efficiency, depending on floating-point format and register size).

I am not sure how well the two GPUs you mentioned handle double-precision math. Typically they're optimized for single precision (32-bit floats), dropping to a third or a quarter of that speed when handling doubles.

There are other factors in your tests that may skew the results. For example, you may be including the matrix transfer time to the CPU. Whether that matches real world use cases, I don't know; I don't have an Nvidia GPU to test.. but I suspect not. Usually there are multiple operations, and the matrix does not need to be transferred between operations.

I've been writing my own low-level SSE3 matrix functions using SSE/AVX vector built-in functions provided by GCC and ICC C99 compilers; early testing indicates it beats the current Fortran implementations by a wide margin, especially at the very small (say up to 8x8, optimized for each size) and very large (above 1000x1000, using Strassen algorithm) sizes for dense matrices.

Comment: Naive matrix mul will vectorize nicely too, isn't it? How is your own lowlevel vs atlas or GotoBLAS?